# Leer y procesar mas de un archivo plano JAVA

Tags: java

tengo un metodo que me permite leer y cargar en la base de datos un archivo plano, lo lee y separa hasta finalmente cargarlo en la tabla.
El problema es que me gustaria poder lograr hacer una "carga masiva de los datos" es decir, poder leer y cargar mas de un archivo seleccionado por el usuario.
Actualmente muestro los .txt en una lista. Ayuda Porfavor!!!

public class CargaConciliacion {
    public boolean leeArchivo(String doc) {
        boolean proceso=true;
        String path = "C://TMP/";

```
    String[] files = getFiles( path );
    File InFile = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    int ultimoRegistro=0;

    try {


        proceso=false;


        String anterior="0";
        Connection cn3=DataBaseConnectionProvider.getConnectionFruna();


        String sql3="SELECT * FROM Conc_Cabezera WHERE numero = (SELECT MAX(numero) FROM Conc_Cabezera) ";
        PreparedStatement state3 = cn3.prepareStatement(sql3);
        ResultSet res3=state3.executeQuery();

        if(res3!=null) {
            while(res3.next()) {
                anterior=res3.getString(3);
            }
        }


        //---------------------------------------------

        if ( files != null ) {

        int size = files.length;
        int x;


        for ( x = 1; x <= size; x ++ ) {

            //System.out.println( files[ x-1 ] );                                                                   

                try{
                    fr =new FileReader(files[ x-1 ]);
                    br=new BufferedReader(fr);
                    String sCadena;
                     String cuenta;
                     String año;
                     String n_cartola;
                     String fecha;
                     String detalle;
                     String cargo;
                     String documento;


                     String ano_fecha;
                     String mes_fecha;
                     String dia_fecha;

                     String fechaCom;
                     String sql;
                     String saldo_inicial= null;
                     String saldo_final = null;

                     int cuenta_int=0;
                     int año_int=0;
                     int n_cartola_int=0;
                     int counter=0;
                     int linea=0;
                     int counterBD=0;
                     int numero_cartola=0;
                     String[] cartola=null;
                     String anho = null;
                     Connection cn = null;

                     Date fechaActual1 = new Date();  

                     Connection cn2 = null;
                    cn2 = DataBaseConnectionProvider.getConnectionFruna();
                    String sql2="select count(numero) from conc_cabezera ";
                    PreparedStatement state2 = cn2.prepareStatement(sql2);
                    ResultSet res1=state2.executeQuery();

                    while(res1.next()) {
                        ultimoRegistro=res1.getInt(1)+1;
                    }


                     //Formateando la fecha:
                     DateFormat formatoHora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss S");
                     DateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                     System.out.println("Inicio Proceso: "+formatoHora.format(fechaActual1)+" de fecha: "+formatoFecha.format(fechaActual1));

                    cartola = files[ x-1 ].toString().split("-");
                    numero_cartola = Integer.parseInt(cartola[1].substring(1, cartola[1].length()-4));
                    anho = cartola[0].substring(cartola[0].length()-8, cartola[0].length()-4);
                    fecha = cartola[0].substring(cartola[0].length()-8, cartola[0].length());

                    while(( sCadena=br.readLine())!=null){

                        //System.out.println(sCadena);

                        /*CABECERA 3 PRIMERAS LINEAS*/

                        linea++;
                        if (linea==3) {
                            saldo_final = sCadena.substring(36, 47);
                            //System.out.println(saldo_inicial);

                            sql="insert into Conc_Cabezera values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

                          cn = DataBaseConnectionProvider.getConnectionFruna();
                          PreparedStatement state = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                          state.setInt(1, ultimoRegistro);
                          state.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(anho));
                          state.setString(3, saldo_final);
                          state.setString(4, fecha);
                          state.setString(5, anterior);
                          state.setString(6, fecha);
                          state.setString(7,doc);           

                          state.executeUpdate();                                 
                          DataBaseConnectionProvider.close(cn, state, null);


                        }                                                   


                        if (counterBD==0 && linea>3){
                            cn = DataBaseConnectionProvider.getConnectionFruna();       
                        }

                        if (linea>3) {  

                        //sql="insert into Conc_Detalle values("+cuenta+","+año+","+n_cartola+",'"+fechaCom+"','"+detalle+"','"+cargo+"','"+documento+"')";
                          sql="insert into Conc_Detalle values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

                          PreparedStatement state = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                          state.setString(1, doc);
                          state.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(anho));
                          state.setInt(3, ultimoRegistro);
                          state.setString(4, fecha);
                          state.setString(5, sCadena.substring(51, 96).trim());
                          state.setString(6, sCadena.substring(36, 47).trim());
                          state.setString(7, sCadena.substring(29, 36).trim());
                         state.setString(8, sCadena.substring(96, 97).trim());

                          state.executeUpdate();
                         counterBD++;
                         if (counterBD==50){
                            counterBD=0;
                            DataBaseConnectionProvider.close(cn, state, null);
                         }

                          counter++; 

                        }

                    }
                    proceso=true;
                     //Formateando la fecha:
                    Date fechaActual = new Date();
                    //System.out.println("Inicio Proceso: "+formatoHora.format(fechaActual1)+" de fecha: "+formatoFecha.format(fechaActual1));
                    System.out.println("Fin Proceso: "+formatoHora.format(fechaActual)+" de fecha: "+formatoFecha.format(fechaActual));
                    System.out.println("Lineas: "+counter);


                  }catch(Exception e){
                      proceso = false;
                      System.out.println(e);
                  }                                

            }
        }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        proceso = false;
        ex.printStackTrace();   
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    return proceso;

}
public static String[] getFiles( String dir_path ) {

    String[] arr_res = null;

    File f = new File( dir_path );

    if ( f.isDirectory( )) {

        List<String> res   = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] arr_content = f.listFiles();

        int size = arr_content.length;

        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i ++ ) {

            if ( arr_content[ i ].isFile( ))
            res.add( arr_content[ i ].toString( ));
        }


        arr_res = res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );

    } else
        System.err.println( "¡ Path NO válido !" );


    return arr_res;
}
```

}

Comment: Revisa el tema de hilos, puedes hacer un metodo que lea el archivo el cual por cada archivo creas un hilo de ejecución.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hola amigo lo que puedes realizar es crear el método de leer archivos y mandarlo a traer la veces que sea necesario, y para la cuestión de diversos archivos puedes utilizar hilos.

Comment: Hola, echale un vistazo a [answer] para poder elaborar una buena respuesta, aporta datos, ejemplos, código... Para que sea lo mas completa posible, un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes el arreglo con la ruta de los archivos que quieres procesar, solo deberás encerrar tu método en un ciclo:

```
for(String archivo: arr_res) //Suponiendo que tu lista con los nombres sea arr_res
    procesaArchivo(archivo);//¿Qué parámetro recibe tu método?
```

Esto lo puse porque tu método regresa un arreglo, pero tu mencionas una lista, en caso de ser una lista o un arraylist, modificalo

Por cierto, tu clase CargaConciliacion no tiene constructor, deberías añadirlo.

Comment: Estimado, cuando hablo de una "lista" me refiero a un tipico listbox con todos los .txt que tengo en la caarpeta C:\\tmp. (Esos me los muestra en un JSP) luego envio de ese JSP A OTRO JSP donde es allí finalmente que  que llamo al metodo leeArchivo() y si esta todo OK me manda el mensaje correspondiente: Tengo CargaConciliacion.jsp (que es donde tengo el formulario con los archivos a la vista del usuario) - CargaFichero (que es un jsp solo para mostrar el mensaje y que llama al metodo leeArchivo()) y finalmente tengo el Carga.java, que es donde tengo el metodo que publique